# Is it possible to write a .NET library that targets .NET 4.0 but uses .NET 4.5 features if invoked by a .NET 4.5 application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

The library must be able to run on machines that have only .NET 4.0. If run on machines that also have .NET 4.5, and if invoked by a .NET 4.5 application, it would be nice if the same library was able to use some .NET 4.5 specific functionality.

Of course, hardcoding dependencies on types and methods that were not introduced until .NET 4.5 would make the library no longer .NET 4.0 compliant, but is it possible for a .NET 4.0 library that was loaded by a .NET 4.5 application to load and use .NET 4.5 types and methods using reflection?

Comment: If you're taking the time to write the whole thing using 4.0, what do you gain by also writing a parallel 4.5 implementation?

Comment: can you not set this in the .cong file for example something like this is what I am doing in mine 
`<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />`

Comment: You could write two different assemblies then add them both as resources into a third assembly, then have that third assembly load the appropriate assembly on load.

Comment: This is too broad because the approach used for different .NET 4.5 features would vary widely.

Comment: Assembly bindings to a specific version could be useful here http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#BKMK_Specifyingassemblybindinginconfigurationfiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can,since they are already at your disposal. One good example is something Paint.Net does; It is compiler for 4.0 but if 4.5 is installed, it enables multi-core JIT using reflection. You can find details in http://blog.getpaint.net/2012/09/08/using-multi-core-jit-from-net-4-0-if-net-4-5-is-installed/